# or condition in logstash grok for a particular field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have the following log pattern

```
2021-04-14T10:57:33+00:00 fihe3nok1789 info Wed Apr 14 10:57:31 2021 : Auth: (14539) Rejected in post-auth: [host/N-20HEPF0W4YKX.fw-intra.net] (from client ro1015w-ws-elm-a-1.ro.fw.com port 0 cli 44032CA08674) - wlan - proxy: 10.130.0.98
```

And I try to match the above with the below grok pattern

```
(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}\s*%{DATA:radius_server}\s*info).*?host\/%{DATA:hostname}\..*?(client\s*%{GREEDYDATA:client}\s*).*?(port\s*%{NUMBER:port}\s*).*?(cli\s*%{MAC:mac_address}\s*|cli\s*%{WORD:mac_address}\s*)
```

But my issue is that, everything works fine till the

> (cli\s*%{MAC:mac_address}\s*|cli\s*%{WORD:mac_address}\s*)

part of the grok. When the grok pattern contains the above piece, it is not working.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: try adding `\)` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Following pattern should work for you:

```
(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}\s*%{DATA:radius_server}\s*info).*?host\/%{DATA:hostname}\..*?(client\s*%{GREEDYDATA:client}\s*).*?(port\s*%{NUMBER:port}\s*).*?(cli\s*%{MAC:mac_address}\s*|cli\s*%{WORD:mac_address}\s*)\) \- wlan \- proxy\: %{IPV4:proxyIp}
```